# How to create a seprate directory like whatsapp for andriod app

Tags: android

I am developing an app which generates some content. I want to create an **app specific folder** in internal storage like  whatsapp,which has it's own folder called "whatsapp", That should be visible by any file explorer.

```
 File myDir = new File(getFilesDir()+ "/" + "abc");
 myDir.mkdir();
```

This code is creating file,but I am not able to see it using file explorer. 
I want folder like whatsapp has.

Comment: That code does create nothing. getExternalFilesDir() ?

Comment: I want to store in internal storage

Comment: That is internal storage.

Comment: you use getExternalFilesDir() to get the path on your primary external storage, which is a space outside of your app but still on the device (not on an SD card). This way anything you put there will be visible from a file explorer.

Comment: I tried this code .. new File(getExternalFilesDir(null)+ "/" + "abc");  It is generating folder . But still it is not accessible from file explorer. Whatsapp folder is visible.

Comment: Are you on Android Q? If not than any file explorer will show you the abc directory. Please tell full path of abc.

Comment: Do you think we know what the whatsapp folder is named like and where it would reside? Full path please.